# ElasticSearch : force refresh of index store.size

Tags: elasticsearch

I spent few hours on this issue, and would appreciate some insights from the community.

I am doing some experiments on a sandbox "single-cluster / single-index" ElasticSearch (v7.17) implementation.

What I intend to achieve is monitor index's memory usage.
To do so, I check index's store.size.
When higher than threshold, my program deletes some documents from it.
Then I would like to check index's store.size to evaluate the new memory usage.

I understand that the delete API will only tag documents as deleted (and not actually delete them), that documents are copied at some point, and that storage increases at short term.

I am aware that this is not exactly how elasticsearch is supposed to be used. Yet this is what I need to achieve.

I tried various API features: Refresh, Forcemerge+Expunge, Flush, Clear Clache …
Even if it results in setting deleted.docs count to 0, the store.size is not updated immediately.
I believe there is a periodic operation performed by elastic, which results in an updated value for store.size, but I did not manage to find out which (and if it’s set at cluster-level or index-level).

My (experimental) sequence is the following:

- I create an index.
- I push some documents in my index.
- I check index’s store.size.
- I perform a delete_by_query on my index (delete some documents, not all of them).
- I perform a forcemerge?only_expunge_deletes=true.
- I perform a flush on my index.
- I perform a clear/cache on my index.
- I perform a refresh on my index.
- I check index’s store.size and expect it to be lower than before the delete request.

Every request returns a success, yet at the end of my sequence, the store.size of my index is bigger than before deletion.
After a while, index’s store.size finally returns a lower value (some background elastic processing I guess).

My question: is there a way to get an up-to-date value for index’s store.size right after my documents are deleted from the index ?

Thank you.